# Unable to access private classes in com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to create an entity following the step 20 in the SDK Tutorials. But when I build the project with the command `mvn clean install`

I added the following imports that are available in 
https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/05fbf11f8ccc403dba4f90150e8f4ccf/1.0/en-US/index.html?com/sap/cloud/sdk/s4hana/datamodel/odata/namespaces/package-summary.html

```
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.AddressEmailAddress;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartnerAddress;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartnerRole;
```

I see the following error.

> [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/sanke/workspace/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/application/src/main/java/com/yash/cf/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/BusinessPartnerServlet.java:[81,17]
>   toEmailAddress(java.util.List)
>   has private access in
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartnerAddress.BusinessPartnerAddressBuilder
>   [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/sanke/workspace/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/application/src/main/java/com/yash/cf/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/BusinessPartnerServlet.java:[93,17]
>   toBusinessPartnerAddress(java.util.List)
>   has private access in
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartner.BusinessPartnerBuilder
>   [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/sanke/workspace/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/application/src/main/java/com/yash/cf/Businesspartners_cloudfoundry/BusinessPartnerServlet.java:[94,17]
>   toBusinessPartnerRole(java.util.List)
>   has private access in
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartner.BusinessPartnerBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog still refers to version 1.5.0. The error you have indicates that you are using a more recent version >= 1.6.0 where the signature of navigation properties has changed slightly. For example, instead of `toEmailAddress(List<AddressEmailAddress> value)` the methods have been reworked to `emailAddress(AddressEmailAddress... value)`. Please also consult the [release notes for 1.6.0](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/release-notes/#version-160) on this matter.

Therefore, please change your code to the following:

```
final BusinessPartnerAddress businessPartnerAddress = BusinessPartnerAddress.builder()
    .country(country)
    .cityName(city)
    .emailAddress(emailAddress)
    .build();
```

The tutorial has been updated as well.